# Hybrid App Maker vs Mobile Frameworks

Tags: mobile, frameworks, ionic-framework

When do you think is best to to use a mobile App Maker (Ex: Appery.io) and when to code using a framework (Ex: Ionic)?

Of course, that coding with a framework doesn't tie you to any App Maker label... But, besides that, any other matter I should consider.

I need to start a simple project that querys a some REST API and have some doubts.
So I thought about posting here to open my head to someone who has walked this road before.

I don't mean this to be an open ended question on what is the best framework and comparing them all. I am just trying to establish is it really necessary to go down the heavier more complicated frameworks or can I get a mature long term solution using something like Appery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to mobile apps, and as in your case, apps that load dynamic data from server, it is usually better to go for mobile app frameworks rather than, for online app builders. There can be multiple reasons for this :

1. App builders usually come with a lot of features, but they almost always fail for some **Custom** client requirements.
2. They usually tend to cater the need for static apps, when it comes to dynamic apps that have a lot of data manipulation stuff, you should prefer your own framework and logic to do so..
3. You can almost everytime modify / tweak a framework, You can't do so with an appbuilder.
4. You aren't sharing your code on cloud [Matters if you are working for some critical organization / client].
5. You have total control over your code / view. You can tweak it, twist it and almost guarantee total ownership. All you are bound to is the limitation your framework imposes.
6. You can mix and match frameworks, that doesn't applies for an appbuilder.

   > These are some of my quick thoughts, there can be [and are] many more reasons for switching towards a mobile framework..

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What about development time? Do you think it worth considering an app maker taking into account development time?

Comment: When it comes to development time, do consider the time that will be spent in exploring for alternatives in case you don't have any possible implementation of a use case in your app maker.

Answer (score 0):

AppMakers are generally there as tools for Rapid Prototyping. These days they market that you can make production apps using Appmakers but when you start using them you will notice that one or some other requirement you have cannot be implemented. In my experience, app development time seems to be less for AppMakers but it is generally more. On the other hand Mobile App Frameworks provide a lot of flexibility and code reusability too.